# Override core Js file

Tags: 8, theming

Working on my theme

I need to override a core Js file ..\core\modules\contextual\js\contextual.js

My code from theme.info

```
libraries-override:
  contextual/drupal.contextual-links:
    js:
      js/contextual.js: js/override/contextual.js
```

The problem is that the loading order of this component js files did change after the override which cause script errors :

[image]

So how can override file js core and still same order file?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks can be done with with the [hook_js_alter function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x)

```
    function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {        
    $javascript['js/contextual.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . 'js/override/contextual.js';
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Sam!!, thanks for the example, I actually searched a lot to override the library inside my custom module and NOT in the theme as asked by @John. Using the ```libraries-override``` approach I was not able to achieve the goal so does that mean it is available for the theme only does not work for the module ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I've applied to override a base theme js Library by overriden js Library in custom theme:
Two files are concerned:

- custom_theme.libraries.yml
- custom_theme.info.yml

**In .libraries.yml file :**

```
mycontextextual.links:
  js:
    js/override/contextual.js: {}
```

**In .info.yml file:**

```
libraries-override:
  contextual/drupal.contextual-links: custom_theme/mycontextual.links
```

I hope it will help.